# 1.5.3 of Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory

Tags: geometry, lie-algebras

[image]

I've been considering this problem as the hand-drawn illustration as shown below.

[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve it using this approach. My attempt was to demonstrate that two triangles, centered on R, are isosceles triangles, but I have not been successful.

I am currently seeking guidance on where I may have gone wrong
(I already read
[Three lines and three rotations using reflections.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251117/three-lines-and-three-rotations-using-reflections)
and I didn't understand it.)

Comment: $$R_Q(\phi)\circ R_P(\theta)=S_{\cal{N}}\circ S_{\cal{M}}\circ S_{\cal{M}}\circ S_{\cal{L}}=S_{\cal{N}}\circ S_{\cal{L}}=R_R(\chi)$$

Answer (score -1):

I am sharing a solution provided by my colleague, Dr. Hosung Joo.

Using the SAS Congruence rule,
we have SPR = S'PR and S'QR = S''QR.
Consequently, SRS'' is an isosceles triangle.